# How can i make list items in a horizontal container fill the entire container evenly without spacing between?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've made a horizontal list using flexbox that fills its container evenly.

But when i try to change the background of the list items during hover etc. you can see there is empty space between each element. Is there any way to get rid of this while still making the list items fill the entire width of the container?

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none
}

li:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>789</li>
    <li>XYZ</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For example here the items are evenly spaced, but there's lots of space between each item.

What i want is something like this when i hover over a list item:

[image]

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Any reason this is tagged Bootstrap?

Comment: @ZimSystem to bother ZimSystem :p

Comment: hahaha, LOL @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all extern padding/margin then use `flex:1` and padding within `li`:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  color: black;
  flex:1;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none
}

li:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>789</li>
    <li>XYZ</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Removing the padding and margins did the trick. Also added flex: 1 0 auto to prevent text wrapping.

Comment: @mTv yes you have a lot of posibilities with flex property to achieve this ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>789</li>
    <li>XYZ</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```